# How can I show xna graphics content in a control on a form in xna?

Tags: xna, level-design, windows-forms

I was able to create a form in xna using "Add Windows Form", named "Form1" then adding:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

How can I add graphics to some control, perhaps a picturebox, on Form1 that could potentially show my game as in a level editor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has an official tutorial on this: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1

> "or maybe you're writing a level editor and want to place Windows user interface controls around the 3D drawing surface"

Basically, you embed your game as a control in a winform.